# document createTextNode confusion

Tags: javascript, dom

Here i have an example where the first child of an unordered list is replaced using element.replaceChild() method.To replace the previous node a textNode is created using documen.createTextNode().But the problem is as its called replaceChild method then it should replace the child.And i am replacing it with a textNode.But surprisingly the replaced child has a bullet tag infront it.As textNode is not a list item then why the bullet tag is not removed.Though the question is not a serious one.Posted it only to meet my curiosity.thanks!!

[jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t17f2nuo/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList"><li>Coffee</li><li>Tea</li><li>Milk</li></ul>

<p id="demo">Click the button to replace the first item in the the list</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var textnode=document.createTextNode("Water");
var item=document.getElementById("myList").childNodes[0];
item.replaceChild(textnode,item.childNodes[0]);
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you checked the output of it? how is it rendered in your dom?

Comment: Notice, that a text node as a direct child of [`ul`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item` refers to the first `li` element. Then you are replacing the first child of `li` element (`item.childNodes[0]`), which is the text node `Coffee`.

You are never replacing the `li` element, just its contents.

If you want to replace the `li` element, use

```
var item=document.getElementById("myList");
```

instead.

Comment: thanks!!that makes sense. :) .i was thinking of using item.replaceChild(textnode,item.firstChild);

Comment: `item.childNodes[0]` is equivalent to `item.firstChild`.